# Missing Right parenthesis error when using variables

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql

I am new to working with oracle and I am trying to use variables to view the current month from the SYSDATE. But no matter how many combinations I tried I get an error stating that there is a missing right parenthesis.

Would really appreciate your help here, thanks!

```
DECLARE
    sys_month NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN   
    sys_month := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MON'));
    dbms_output.put_line('Current Month: ' || sys_month);
END;
/
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the error you get, with the **exact** code you posted? I get something else altogether - "Numeric or value error". The reason is obvious: if you use the `'MON'` format model, that returns an abbreviation for month (something like `JAN`, `AUG` or `DEC`); you can't apply `to_number()` to that. To extract the month number from a date, use something like `extract(month from sysdate)` instead.

Comment: You could also use `'MM'` instead of `'MON'`. [Read more about Oracle datetime format models](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A).

Comment: @kfinity - sure, but why? `extract` returns a number directly; the way you suggest we format the month as a string, then call one more function. "could" but "shouldn't" - agree?

Comment: @mathguy - yes! thanks for clarifying. For maintainability, I think beginners often prefer familiar functions like `to_number` and `to_char`, but they really should learn how to use `extract` since it's more efficient.

Comment: Yeah I am not sure why either, the error that I am getting is a missing right parenthesis error. ORA-00907 to be exact. Thank you so much for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

> But no matter how many combinations I tried I get an error stating that there is a missing right parenthesis.

Your code is syntactically valid and does not generate a "missing right parenthesis" error. If you are getting that error then it would be from some other code (before or after) as your code:

```sql
DECLARE
    sys_month NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN   
    sys_month := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MON'));
    dbms_output.put_line('Current Month: ' || sys_month);
END;
/
```

Fails with a run-time exception (rather than a compile-time error):

> ```
> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
> ORA-06512: at line 4
> ```

Because you are converting the current date to a string like `DEC` for the `MON`th and then trying to convert that string to a number; which fails as it contains alphabetic characters and no digits.

---

To fix that error, as pointed out by [@mathguy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70156931/missing-right-parenthesis-error-oracle-sql-when-using-variables/70157331?noredirect=1#comment124018002_70156931), you can use `EXTRACT` to do it in a single function call:

```
DECLARE
    sys_month NUMBER := EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE);
BEGIN   
    dbms_output.put_line('Current Month: ' || sys_month);
END;
/
```

Or, if you really did want to convert to a string and then to a number, you can use the `MM` format model:

```sql
DECLARE
    sys_month NUMBER := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM'));
BEGIN   
    dbms_output.put_line('Current Month: ' || sys_month);
END;
/
```

Which both output:

> ```
> Current Month: 11
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3fcdb84bb0b65545db274ab7dd4f90fe)*

Comment: @mathguy If you want to make an answer and get the points then I can delete this one if it really bothers you. I don't care about the virtual points; I was just trying to be helpful and provide an answer in the space where answers go and not in ephemeral comments (which, unfortunately, I hadn't read).

Comment: No, that's not what I meant (or care about). In a very similar situation a few days ago, I posted an answer rather than a question, beginning with a speculation as to what the OP really meant (and then giving an answer based on that speculation). You pointed out that questions for clarification are comments, rather than answers. You did have a point then. But then I saw what was happening here, whence my observation. I don't care about this so-called "reputation" any more than you do, I believe we both know it has no value whatsoever.

Comment: @mathguy I've edited so that it addresses: the OP's assumed problem; the reason for the OP's actual problem; given you credit for the your comment; and converted it to a community wiki. There are three routes that could be taken with the question: either close the question as not reproducible as the OP's error message is impossible to generate with their code; wait for the OP to clarify the question; or answer the actual problem with their code. If you want to change anything then just edit the community wiki.

Comment: My preference (others' may be different) is to wait for the OP to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like so.

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
    sys_month varchar2(60) ;
BEGIN   
    sys_month := (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MON'));
    dbms_output.put_line('Current Month: ' || sys_month);
END;
/
```

This will return `Nov`.